# How can I call a function of an iterator while passing the vector I am iterating over?

Tags: vector, iterator, rust

I am trying to iterate over a vector of structures and call a function from the iterator while also passing the vector into it.

I get this error:

```
error[E0502]: cannot borrow `self.members` as immutable because it is also borrowed as mutable
  --> main.rs:40:29
   |
39 |             for member in self.members.iter_mut() {
   |                           ------------ mutable borrow occurs here
40 |                 member.func(self.members.to_vec());
   |                             ^^^^^^^^^^^^ immutable borrow occurs here
41 |             }
   |             - mutable borrow ends here

error[E0502]: cannot borrow `self.members` as immutable because it is also borrowed as mutable
  --> main.rs:40:29
   |
39 |             for member in self.members.iter_mut() {
   |                           ------------ mutable borrow occurs here
40 |                 member.func(self.members.to_vec());
   |                             ^^^^^^^^^^^^ immutable borrow occurs here
41 |             }
   |             - mutable borrow ends here
```

I understand what the issue is, but don't really know the syntax to get around it.
I've tried various different things like cloning and copying but can't quite seem to get it to work appropriately.

```
struct Member {
    data: i32,
}

impl Copy for Member {}
impl Clone for Member {
    fn clone(&self) -> Member {
        *self
    }
}

impl Member {
    pub fn new(data: i32) -> Member {
        Member { data: data }
    }
    pub fn func(&mut self, members: Vec<Member>) {
        let mut exists = false;
        for member in members.iter() {
            if member.data == self.data + 1 {
                exists = true;
            }
        }
        if !exists {
            self.data += 1;
        }
    }
}

struct List {
    members: Vec<Member>,
}

impl List {
    pub fn new() -> List {
        let mut members = Vec::new();
        members.push(Member::new(0));
        members.push(Member::new(1));
        members.push(Member::new(3));
        List { members: members }
    }

    pub fn call_all(&mut self) {
        // Here is the issue
        for member in self.members.iter_mut() {
            member.func(self.members.to_vec());
        }
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut list = List::new();
    list.call_all();
}
```

It seems that it would be a simple fix.
If this seems too generic check out this [repo of the full code](https://github.com/barrettTom/roma).

Comment: This seems too artifical and vague. Can you be more specific in what actual problem you are trying to solve? How do you want to update the members really? What version of the vector would you like to pass to `func` for this? Do you need changes to be immediately visible for the next iteration? There is a good reason why Rust doesn't let you do this. But it's difficult to suggest a *good* solution when I don't really know what problem you're trying to solve.

Comment: okay I edited it to be more like my code. Specifically I check that the data exists anywhere else in the members and if it doesn't, allow to change the data.

Comment: so then would be the best method of implementing something of this nature?

Comment: The answer is going to be dependent upon whether you want to pass the original `Member` values to `func` or should each subsequent call to `func` include any `Member` values which were previously mutated?

Comment: The latter, which I believe is answered by sellibitze?

Answer (score 0):

It's important that you understand the borrowing restrictions. There can only be one mutable borrow of something and as long as that borrow is "alive" you can't access that thing using any other means. Rust does not allow you to access the same thing in different ways while one of those ways allows mutation. That's how we get to all those nice safety guarantees.

In your code you borrow `self.members` mutably using `iter_mut` as part of the loop construct. That's why the compiler doesn't let you access `self.members` again inside the loop.

I don't know what the purpose of your code is but this seems to compute what you wanted to compute:

```
fn main() {
    let mut v = vec![0, 1, 3];
    for i in 0..v.len() {
        if !v.contains(&(v[i] + 1)) {
            v[i] += 1;
        }
    }
    println!("{:?}", &v[..]);
}
```

Here, the vector isn't borrowed as part of the loop construct. We iterate over indices instead. The condition in the `if` expression involves two temporary immutable borrows which is fine. In the `if` expression's body `v` is temporarily borrowed mutably to change the value of the `i`-th element while no other borrow is live. That's OK.

Comment: pub fn call_all(&mut self) {
        for i in 0..self.members.len() {
            self.members[i].action(self.members);
        }
    } Doesn't seem like it would work though, I would get a similar issue.

Comment: Exactly. You're still trying to violate the aliasing/mutation rules. Either lift the code of the Member method into the loop or at least separate it into two functions: one that checks the condition taking &self and one that mutates it taking &mut self but no other reference to the complete vector.

Comment: There are other options, too (involving interior mutability) but I wouldn't go that path in this instance.

Comment: You can't create a mutable reference into a vector and borrow the vector as a whole at the same time.

Comment: i've posted the repo for the full code, I'm sure many things I have done aren't very rustacean but it's my first project with it, let me know if you see any major design flaws.